# Return to the begin of a line of an input file , C++

Tags: c++, line, fstream

i have a problem with fstream in C++. If i open a file , for example test.txt, and i want to read each line checking if the first value that i take isn't a string. If it isn't a string the line is therefore formed by numerical values.If i check the first i lost the first value that i need. If i want to return to the begin of line how can i made this?  I have tried with `seekg(*,ios::cur)` but i don't know how many position i have to go back to return to the begin of line.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you question correctly, you want to read the first word in each line and then do something with that info, and return to the first character in the line again.

```
ifstream fin;
string text;

fin.open("test.txt");
fin >> text;
```

`text.size()` will give you the length of the first word, because the >> operator only reads up to the first white space. So, using that info you now know how many characters to go back.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is you read the line into a string then you can cut out what you need using `substr` for example check if it's a number and then read the next line.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::ifstream file( "file.txt" );
std::string line;

while( std::getline( file , line ) )
{
    line.substr( 0 , 2 ) // for example the first 2 positions
    // do your checks
}
```

There is also an approach using tokens if you know that each line contains a certain not changing amount of values.
If you provide more information about the actual data in the file I might be able to clarify that for you.

Also I recommend checking if the string is empty, maybe even trim it before to make sure you don't have empty lines or checking for the size of the line string that you don't try to cut out something that isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a check before reading the line.

```
ifstream foo("bar.txt");

if(isdigit(foo.peek())){
    // You're getting a number
}else{
    // You're getting a string
}
```

`peek` doesn't remove a character so you could proceed as though nothing was read.